# MySQL Group Nearest Timed Events

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a MySQL table containing a log with 4 different events. Each event is logged every 15 or so minutes on its own row, but they're not consistently captured at the same time each time.

Table structure:

```
id  datetime  eventtype  data
```

I need to perform some calculations from all 4 events captured in the same basic timeframe, typically within 5 minutes of each other. For example, events 1 and 2 may be captured at 10:41 and 10:42 respectively, while event 3 gets captured at 10:44, and event 4 arrives even later at 10:45.

The problem is that any event could be a minute or more ahead or behind others. Is there a way I can select and group the rows of each event type within the nearest timeframe?

Some inaccuracy is to be expected as it's possible for one event to not come in, or even get pushed a few minutes and become part of the next timeframe instead. I just need to ensure that any given grouping will have a valid event for each event type (which I can check at the time of the calculation).

I started with *group by*, but failed miserably since the datetime isn't the same for each event. This will be a large table so I don't think it makes sense to loop through rows and perform the math/grouping one by one, at least I hope it's not the best way. I'm not sure where to turn next. Any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Sample Data

```
id  datetime  eventtype  data  
 1   10:41     1          67  
 2   10:45     4          14  
 3   10:42     2          12  
 4   10:44     3          87  
 5   10:57     1          63  
 6   10:59     4          13  
 7   10:59     2          19  
 8   11:01     3          01
```

Results from desired query:

```
          datetime  event1 event2 event3 event4  
Result 1:  10:41     67     12     87     14  
Result 2:  10:57     63     19     01     13
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: `14     87     14` !?!?

Comment: mysql and complex group by will lead you to sever performance issue

Comment: I started down the path of performing the calcs in the application code, but felt it would drastically impact the web server performance when running calculations across days, weeks or even more. However, it sounds like this may be the best option due to the complexity.